# namespace-name not recognized

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following two sample c++ files:

File: foo.cc

```
namespace test_ns {
int x = 100;
}
```

File: bar.cc

```
using namespace test_ns;

extern int x;

int main()
{
    x = 200;
    return 0;
}
```

I must be doing something really silly as I am getting the following compiler error:
    bar.cc:2:17: error: 'test_ns' is not a namespace-name
    bar.cc:2:24: error: expected namespace-name before ';' token

However, my main question (after I resolve the namespace error), with the code as is, should I be able to use "x" in bar.cc, or do I need to use additional qualifiers.

Sorry to bother with such a simple issue, but I am pretty stumped with such a simple program.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like every other name in C++, a namespace name must be declared before it can be accessed. When compiling `bar.cc`, the compiler doesn't know `test_ns` is a namespace name - you haven't provided a declaration for it.

Namespaces and `using namespace` aren't magical tricks that let you get around the necessity to declare anything you want to use. To make this work, create a header file:

**foo.hh**

```
namespace test_ns {
  extern int x;
}
```

Then `#include "foo.hh"` in `bar.cc`, and remove `extern int x;` from `bar.cc`. That will make these two translation units form a valid program. And after you do that, referring to `x` in `bar.cc` will indeed refer to `test_ns::x` (thanks to the `using` directive).

---

As a side note, if you don't remove the `extern int x;` from `bar.cc` (after you include the header file), it will declare a new global variable `::x` and not refer to `test_nest::x`. `using namespace` in a source file allows you to define class members without referring to the class's namespace, but namespace-scope entities (variables and functions) always have to be defined inside the namespace or using a qualified name.

Answer (score 0):

They are in different compilation units. You need to declare the namespace in a common header; which you can do using:

```
namespace test_ns {}
```

Answer (score 0):

namespace is defined in a different file. It needs to be defined in a header file which should be included in bar.cc .